# How to capture numbers using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Given an input string of letters and numbers I am trying to capture the numbers that fit a specific format.

The input sample is as follows:

> Hello my net worth is 1,000,000.00 and i like it

Expected output: 1,000,000.00

```
def detect_numbers(input_numbers_string):

number_format_pattern_map = {
        'us_start_with_decimal_regex': '(\.{1}\d+)$',
        'us_decimal_and_comma_regex': '\d{1,3}(,{1}\d{3})*(\.{1}\d+){0,1}$'
    }
    
fuzzy_matched_substrings = []
fuzzy_match_locations = []
fuzzy_changes = []
matched_formats = []

for numbers in number_format_pattern_map:
    number_pattern_string = number_format_pattern_map[numbers]
    r = regex.compile('(?e)(%s){e<=2}' % number_pattern_string)
    fuzzy_matches = r.finditer(query_string)
    for matches in fuzzy_matches:
         print(matches)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    query_string = 'hello my net worth is 1,000,000.00 and i like it'
    updated_query_string = detect_numbers(query_string)
    print(updated_query_string)
```

I get the expected result when I pass in "1,000,000.00" as the input string. However, when I pass "hello my net worth is 1,000,000.00 and i like it" I get the following result:

> regex.Regex('(?e)((\.{1}\d+)$){e<=2}', flags=regex.V0) <regex.Match
> object; span=(46, 48), match='it', fuzzy_counts=(2, 0, 0)>
> <regex.Match object; span=(48, 48), match='', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 2)>
> regex.Regex('(?e)(\d{1,3}(,{1}\d{3})*(\.{1}\d+){0,1}$){e<=2}',
> flags=regex.V0) <regex.Match object; span=(47, 48), match='t',
> fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)> <regex.Match object; span=(48, 48), match='',
> fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 1)> regex.Regex('(?e)((,{1}\d+)$){e<=2}',
> flags=regex.V0) <regex.Match object; span=(46, 48), match='it',
> fuzzy_counts=(2, 0, 0)> <regex.Match object; span=(48, 48), match='',
> fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 2)>
> regex.Regex('(?e)(\d{1,3}(\.{1}\d{3})*(,{1}\d+){0,1}$){e<=2}',
> flags=regex.V0) <regex.Match object; span=(47, 48), match='t',
> fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)> <regex.Match object; span=(48, 48), match='',
> fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 1)>

This only captures it and t whereas it should capture 1,000,000.00 and similar substrings. Any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: What is the longer string you are testing on?

Comment: Use this for a fuzzy match regex `[\d.,]+`

Comment: Try one of these `(?<![^\d.])(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` or `(?<![^\d.])(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})`

Comment: It is much easier for readers to figure out what you are trying to do if you state your question at the beginning without any reference to your code, then give one or more examples, showing the desired result for each.

Comment: @Maxt8r the only acceptable number formats for this case would be numbers with correct commas and decimal or numbers without decimal but appropriate commas (ie. 1,000,000.00 or 100,000 or 1,000,000. Wouldn't [\d.,]+ make it way too flexible and match other number formats that dont fit the expected format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pattern**

```
((?:\d{1,3},)*\d{1,3}\.\d{2})
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Start main capture group

  - `(?:` Non-capture group (omits this group from match results)

    - `\d{1,3},` One to three digits followed by a comma.
  - `)*` End of non-capture group, `*` matches zero or more occurrences. This is non-mandatory, value *can* have a comma (over 1,000) or be under 1,000 (no comma).
  - `\d{1,3}` Covers values 0 through 999 (this is mandatory)
  - `\.\d{2}` Matches `.00` through `.99`
- `)` End main capture group